# $\int_x^a (x-t)f^{''}(t)dt$ = $\int_x^a f^{''}(t)d(\frac {-1}{2} (x-t)^2)$.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is an integrable function on $\Bbb R$, I have encountered the following equality in my notes and I am a tad confused:

$\int_x^a (x-t)f^{''}(t)dt$ = $\int_x^a f^{''}(t)d(\frac {-1}{2} (x-t)^2)$.

Now clearly I know that $\frac {d}{dt}( \frac {-1}{2} (x-t)^2) = (x-t)$, and that you can multiply out the differentials, but I am confused about using what seems to be a polynomial in $d(\frac {-1}{2} (x-t)^2)$. Any clarification much appreciated. What sort of substitution is this?

Comment: @Reveillark No, that's u-substitution in fancy schmancy Leibniz notation. It stems from the ol' chain rule $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$$But instead, the integral form$$\int f(t)\frac{dy}{dt}~dt=\int f(t)~dy$$Not to be confused with [Leibniz notation for antidifferentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Leibniz.27s_notation_for_antidifferentiation) though

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt ok thanks. Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Comment: \*checks the time\* Sorry, I'm about an hour past bed time and I have to get up early. Perhaps you could post your own answer and I'll review it in the morning?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Whoops, good to know, thanks!